# How ls -R displays files (spaces)

Tags: shell, ls

As part of a school project, I have to recode the ls function, partly

However, I do not understand how ls handles spaces with the -R option
The spaces between the columns seem to me to be different, how are they determined?

```
bash-3.2$ ls -R
directory.o display_file.o  file.o          link.o      options.o   recursive.o utils.o
display     display_files.o formatting.o    main.o      path.o      search.o
```

Comment: FYI, the `-R` option doesn't have anything to do with output formatting.  It makes `ls` recursively list subdirectories.

Comment: Your best bet would be to read the source code of `ls`.

Comment: For your school project, I would suspect that if you had some kind of multi-column output you'd be fine. Not sure why you'd need to match the spacing exactly. But if you look carefully, you'll see that `ls` enforces a minimum column width of 12. If you are using `printf`, that would be a format of `%-12s`.